# Using extract function in your own sql function

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, sql-function

I'm trying to create the following function into my Postgres database:

```
create or replace function public.extract_hour(time_param timestamp with time zone) returns double precision language sql as $function$
SELECT EXTRACT(hour from timestamp time_param);
$function$;
```

but I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "time_param"
```

I tried to put instead of `time_param` `$0`, but the same error occur. Can somebody explain me how to solve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, you are using an older version of PostgreSQL (which you neglected to provide). Referring to parameter *names* is possible since PostgreSQL 9.2. In older versions you can only refer to positional parameters:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.extract_hour(time_param timestamptz)
  RETURNS double precision LANGUAGE sql AS
$function$
SELECT EXTRACT(hour from $1);
$function$;
```

Also I removed the misplaced keyword `timestamp`.

While referring to parameter names has been possible in PL/pgSQL functions for a long time now.
[We fixed a documentation glitch to the opposite just recently.](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/18362.1368288613@sss.pgh.pa.us#18362.1368288613@sss.pgh.pa.us)